# What is the best way of dealing with a big mutable struct in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

Here is a simplified view of my problem :

```
struct Game {
    currentPlayer: u8,
    players: Vec<Player>,
    units: Vec<Unit>,
}

fn update(game: &mut Game) {
    for unit in game.units.iter_mut().filter(|u| u.owner == game.currentPlayer) {
        if unit.repairPrice < game.getPlayer(game.currentPlayer).money {
            unit.health = 100;
            game.getPlayer(game.currentPlayer).money -= unit.repairPrice;
        }
    }
}

impl Game {
    pub fn getPlayer(&mut self, player: u8) -> &mut Player {
        return self.players.iter_mut().find(|p| p.color == player).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Here, the compiler says that I can't borrow as immutable the value currentPlayer, because game is already borrowed as mutable.

While I understand what the compiler is saying and why it's saying it, I have no idea what I'm supposed to change to make. Both the unit and the player must be updated at the same time, so it seems no matter how I do it it will always raise a conflict.

I could make a clone of the entire struct, iterate and calculate on that and then finding the corresponding unit and player in the original mutable struct to update them, but that is extremely inefficient.

Comment: In this case, you can just assign the current player to a local variable before entering the loop: `let mut player = game.getPlayer(game.currentPlayer);` and then use that in place of calling the getter within the loop.

Comment: @eggyal: Pretty sure that depends on the definition of `getPlayer`, which they haven't provided; seems like `game.getPlayer(game.currentPlayer)` could, itself, cause a borrowing conflict, and that's before the mutable iteration over `game.units` and the `filter` based on `game.currentPlayer` gets involved. Really, this needs a [MCVE], and this isn't complete, there's too many possible pitfalls without knowing exact ownership semantics here.

Comment: @eggyal That doesn't work, you just end up with an error when borrowing to loop on the units.

Comment: @ShadowRanger getPlayer simply returns a player from the players vector. I made an edit to includ the function in the question, thanks.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Having expanded your code [to a reproducer for your problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b49a1f4a3fc8fd157dcc600d69f04e2a), it's pretty clear you can't make this work without:

1. A substantial refactoring,
2. A lot of wasteful cloning and/or `unsafe` stuff, or
3. Inlining the code of `getPlayer` into `update` (redundant, terrible)

The fundamental problem is, when a function says it mutably borrows an object, [it borrows the *whole* of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25513755/364696). So for `getPlayer`, even though *you* know it only touches the `players` attribute, Rust's borrow checker (which works on function *interfaces*, not *contents*) has to assume it could do anything to the `Game` reference it received.

The most minimal solution I can come up with is to make `getPlayer` be a free function that takes a mutable reference to *only* the `Vec` of `Player` objects, so `update` can be analyzed in a way that makes it clear neither `Vec` is being borrowed more than once.

```
fn update(game: &mut Game) {
    for unit in game.units.iter_mut().filter(|u| u.owner == game.currentPlayer) {
        // Passed mutable reference to the players only, rather than being called on a whole Game
        if unit.repairPrice < getPlayer(&mut game.players, game.currentPlayer).money {
            unit.health = 100;
            // Same change as above
            getPlayer(&mut game.players, game.currentPlayer).money -= unit.repairPrice;
        }
    }
}

// Made a free function so it can accept the Vec alone, not the whole game
fn getPlayer(players: &mut Vec<Player>, player: u8) -> &mut Player {
    return players.iter_mut().find(|p| p.color == player).unwrap();
}
```

[which works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2eb459c0f3a9b91cc365dd6c44ae1669) (though it does complain about your non-idiomatic variable names; `snake_case` FTW, none of this `camelCase` nonsense).

Alternatively, [you inline `getPlayer` into `update`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7fdd022827c8b9e6a5c9b4c912a4e4a7); it need not be too redundant given you could cache the result and only copy the code once, rather than twice (as a bonus, it may mean only doing the work once, rather than twice *per unit* associated with that player); no `getPlayer` is needed at all, you just tweak `update`:

```
fn update(game: &mut Game) {
    let player = game.players.iter_mut().find(|p| p.color == game.currentPlayer).unwrap();
    for unit in game.units.iter_mut().filter(|u| u.owner == game.currentPlayer) {
        if unit.repairPrice < player.money {
            unit.health = 100;
            player.money -= unit.repairPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

That said, I think the better approach here may be to attach a `Vec<Unit>` to *each* `Player`, instead of having it on `Game` instead of managing units separately from players. Done that way, `getPlayer` wouldn't conflict in `update`, because you'd just get the single `Player` object mutably, and operate on the `unit`s attached to it (without touching any other element of the `Game`, and operating more efficiently since you don't need to keep looking up the player, don't need to process every unit, just the ones for that player, etc.). If you need to go through all the `Unit`s as an iterator, a simple `flat_map` would let you iterate the players and combine their units into a single logical iterator.

Comment: It seems very strange that the borrow checker has a problem with getPlayer, but not with inlining it. Is there not way of telling the compiler "inline this function" so that there is no need to copy-paste code ?

Putting the units into the Player struct doesn't solve the fundamental problem that I can't edit 2 variables of a struct at the same time, and I will run into this same problem again and again. This seems like a very big restriction, if it prevents the writing of such a simple piece of code.

Comment: @oui: To avoid unbounded recursive complexity issues, the Rust borrow checker, at any given point, is (simplifying a bit) looking at a single scope at a time. Any calls that leave that scope *only* look at the prototype of the function being called (argument types, return value, and any lifetime annotations associated with them), so if the prototype is inaccurate or overbroad, the borrow checker doesn't notice, it just pays attention to what the interface *claims* to do. If you say you're borrowing a mutable reference to a `Game`, you're allowed to mutate *any* of it.

Comment: This is sometimes helpful; if your function ends up needing to mutate more of the `Game`, it's allowed to do so without changing the `Game` prototype; working code that passes the borrow checker can't start failing borrow checking because of a change in the implementation of one of the functions it calls. But it also makes it a pain in cases like this. Inlining works, because now the borrow checker can see everything, but as a separate function it can only know you made a "mutable borrow of `game.units`" *and* a mutable borrow of `game` (that could legally mutate `game.units`) and complains.